# No data found in Timeseries table and line graph on Dasbhoard Thingsboard

Tags: display, thingsboard, linegraph

everyone

I already made a timeseries table and line graph  in the dashboard.
On 17 August 2022 is work properly, suddenly now I don't know why the data can't be displayed all the time on line graph and timeseries table. this a bugs or is there any way i can do to fix this problem?

Please give me an advice, thanks

*Update
the device is still on, and can send the latest telemetry data
[telemetry data SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnlGv.png)
, but it can't display time series data and line graphs.

[time series image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSND6.png)

[line graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJsPd.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it's hard to tell what's the issue in your case. There could be several causes for this like device inactivity etc.

Please investigate the Log file `thingsboard.log` if there are any issues while sending the data to ThingsBoard.

Alternatively, take a look at the API Usage dashboard to verify that new data is stored in ThingsBoard.

Comment: Hello, the device is still on, and can send the latest telemetry data , but it can't display time series data and line graphs on dashboard.

Comment: Do you see any new data if you select the `Latest Telemetry` Tab of the device?

Comment: Yes, the telemetry data always update on latest telemetry tab. but cannot display on line graph and timeseries data.

Comment: Then it may be a bug. Which ThingsBoard version are you running? Consider updating to the latest version.

Comment: Also there is a similar issue which could be fixed by enable post-processing function as a workaround: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6238

Comment: we used ThingsBoard version 3.3.4.1, we tried to use  enable post-processing function like this https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6238, but still not working.

Comment: Please try updating to the most recent Version of ThingsBoard. This bug may be fixed there.

Comment: i've never update thingsboard before, there's any impact of my old device and dashboard in my system? cause this platform still running on my production.

Answer (score 0):

The Thingsboard time stamps the data. See https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/telemetry/#data-points
If you set the timestamp yourself (through setting element ts in metadata part of your script for examle) and you do it wrong, you may not see anything in the line graph. Try removing all your code that sets the ts (timestamp) and leave it to the thingsboard logic.